# HTML Query String into Perl Hash?

Tags: html, perl, hash, query-string

Typically I've only ever had to pass a handful of values between web pages. To retrieve them, I've typed out, one-by-one, the values I knew would be in the query string. For example...

```perl
my $var = param('input');
```

I'd repeat that for as many times as necessary... which was seldom very many.

However, I find myself in a situation where I have to pass quite a few values. To make matters more interesting, I won't know precisely how many variables or which ones will be passed. It's true, the possibilities are from a finite set but it will be a chore to go through them one by one. It would be nice to be able to pass a hash between web pages with the same efficiency that we pass hashes to and from functions. But I know of no such way. So...

I have worked up two methods for grabbing the HTML query string and saving the results to a hash. One works with the $ENV query string. It works but must use GET, and strings must be cleaned up. The other uses CGI. It can retrieve using the POST method and is generally cleaner than ENV. Both use about the same number of lines of code, with CGI squeaking in one line shorter than ENV.

My question is: Is there an ideal, quick, efficient, confident, problem-free way to pass a hash full of values between web pages? Along those lines I thought it would be better to access the values directly from $query = new CGI() rather than use intermediate steps to recreate the hash and re-save the values? Or, at the very least, copy it directly into a usable hash. I've tried several syntactical variations but no luck. I've read of other configurations but to date they seem more complex than what I've come up with so far.

Here's my examples (mocked up for sake of illustration) so you can see what I've been doing. My actual list of values will be longer than what I've included here.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
my $thispage = $ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'};
$thispage =~ s/(?:.+\/)([^#?]+)/$1/ig;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print qq(<p>Save query string to hash...</p>\n);

my %hash;
my $query_string = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'} ;
my @pairs = split(/\&/, $query_string);
foreach my $pair (@pairs){
 my ($key, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
 $value =~ s/\+/ /g ; 
 $hash{$key} = $value ; 
}

print qq(\n<blockquote><pre>) ;
while ( my ($key,$value) = each %hash) {
# let's make it readable
print sprintf "%-9s", $key;
print "=> $value\n";
}
print qq(</pre></blockquote>\n\n) ;

print qq(<p>
<form action="$thispage" method="GET">
 <input type="hidden" name="Purple" value="Color">
 <input type="hidden" name="Orange" value="Fruit">
 <input type="hidden" name="Family" value="Relatives">
 <input type="hidden" name="Twelve" value="Number">
 <input type="hidden" name="Silver" value="Coins">
 <input type="hidden" name="Thirty" value="Middle aged">
 <input type="hidden" name="People" value="Are Hell">
 <input type="hidden" name="Future" value="Past">
 <input type="hidden" name="Banana" value="Yellow">
 <input type="hidden" name="Africa" value="Continent">
 <input type="hidden" name="Monday" value="Hateful Things">
 <input type="hidden" name="Office" value="Politics">
 <input type="hidden" name="Nature" value="Second">
 <input type="hidden" name="Eleven" value="Tufnel">
 <input type="hidden" name="Animal" value="Muppet">
 <input type="hidden" name="Rachel" value="Ex">
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="ENV Query String to Hash!">
</form>
);

__END__
```

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI qw(:standard);
use strict;
use warnings;
my $thispage = $ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'};
$thispage =~ s/(?:.+\/)([^#?]+)/$1/ig;
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print qq(<p>Save query string to hash...</p>\n);

my %hash;
my $query = new CGI();
my @keys = $query->param;
foreach my $key (@keys ) {
 $hash{$key} = $query->param($key);
}

print qq(\n<blockquote><pre>) ;
while ( my ($key,$value) = each %hash) {
# let's make it readable
print sprintf "%-9s", $key;
print "=> $value\n";
}
print qq(</pre></blockquote>\n\n) ;

print qq(<p>
<form action="$thispage" method="POST">
 <input type="hidden" name="Friday" value="TGIF">
 <input type="hidden" name="Yellow" value="Banana">
 <input type="hidden" name="Poetry" value="Yawn">
 <input type="hidden" name="August" value="Heat">
 <input type="hidden" name="Potato" value="Bobby">
 <input type="hidden" name="Sunday" value="School">
 <input type="hidden" name="Circle" value="Clique">
 <input type="hidden" name="Breath" value="less">
 <input type="hidden" name="Circus" value="Carnival">
 <input type="hidden" name="London" value="Bridge">
 <input type="hidden" name="Energy" value="Bill">
 <input type="hidden" name="Sister" value="Ignatius">
 <input type="hidden" name="Monkey" value="Shines">
 <input type="hidden" name="System" value="Fail">
 <input type="hidden" name="Austin" value="Steve">
 <input type="hidden" name="Secret" value="Policeman's Ball">
 <input type="submit" class="button" value="CGI Query String to Hash!">
</form>
);

__END__
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this. Extra special thanks for considered responses.

Cheers,

Comment: As Dave Cross points out below, there is existing code that will do this for you. When you're faced with a programming problem, ask yourself if it's likely that other folks have run into it, too. If so, look for existing solutions that have already been written, tested and debugged before trying to roll your own.

Comment: Hi Andy. I'm not afraid of a bit of work, or even the time it takes to figure something out in greater detail, but yes, I agree, there is no point reinventing the wheel. Which is why I'm here. I spend a LOT of time reading here and elsewhere. But sometimes it's worth looking for clarification on the subtleties. Cheers, mate. Your interest is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for CGI.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod), you'll see a section entitled "[Fetching the parameter list as a hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-parameter-list-as-a-hash)" which seems to answer your question.

You can either do it using a CGI object:

```
use CGI;

my $q = CGI->new;

my %params = $q->Vars;
```

Or using the function-based interface to the module:

```
use CGI ':cgi-lib';

my %params = Vars();
```

Note, that if you have multiple parameters with the same name (as generated from query string like `param1=foo&param1=bar`) then the value in the hash will be string where the various values will be separated by the character `\0`.

Comment: You're right. Just what I was looking for. One point of clarification, if you could. Is there a difference between my first example - my $q = new CGI() and your configuration - my $q = CGI->new? Or to put it another way, couldn't I have 
just used - my %params = $q->Vars - instead of my @keys = $q->param? Thank you.

Comment: @Bobby: Syntax like `new Class` is known as "indirect object notation". It works fine 99% of the time, but when it breaks you'll waste days trying to track down the problem. The safer and saner way to write it is `Class->new()`. There's no good reason to keep using the older, buggy syntax. I guess you're using an older version of CGI.pm which still uses the dodgy version in its documentation.

Comment: @Bobby: See the section on "Indirect Object Notation" in [perlobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) for more details.

Comment: I'm not sure about using an older version. Maybe the problem is I haven't been coding for years. Things like this are great refreshers. Anyway, I've read the section you pointed to, which let's me know I have much more to read before I'm done. Thank you again.

Comment: Anyone (like me) who wants to combine query string and post parameters needs to remember to do this $CGI::APPEND_QUERY_STRING = 1;